# iOS UiTableViewCell selective cells to show accessoryView

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

My problem is similar as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934761/uitableviewcell-allowing-selective-deletion):

But I want to show accessoryView with DetailDisclosureButton only for cells that have details.

I have written some codes, but I don´t know in which method to put it.

```
if (totalcount == 0 && totalcount2 == 0)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

else 
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

totalcount and totalcount2 is count of two mutable arrays that tell me whether cells have details or not.

Please ask me if my question is not clear, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* identifierString;

    if(totalCount == 0 && totalCount2 == 0) {
        identifierString = @"0";
    } else {
        identifierString = @"1";
    }

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierString];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:YOUR_CELL_STYLE 
            reuseIdentifier:identifierString] autorelease];

        if ([identifierString intValue] == 0) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }

        //do whatever setup you need to do
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Though to me, it seems that if totalCount and totalCount2 both equal 0, then all of the cells are going to have the same accessory type. Is that what you what? If not, you might want to rethink your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are right in that I have to rethink my logic. I thought "cell" was individual, but I realize that it is all or nothing.

Comment: Finally I had time to test this, this solves partially, but do you know how do I read cell.textLabel.text before UITableViewCell *cell is initialized?

Comment: Think about what you're trying to do. You can't read the content of a cell's text label until the cell is initialized. But what you can do is read the text from wherever you are getting it- if you are getting it from an array, you should access the corresponding string in the array.

Comment: It is solved now :-D It is just my mind playing me a joke. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should do that in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, while you're setting up your `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 1):

add this to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` after the cell has been dequeued or initialised

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library . with MSCellAccessory, UITableViewCell's accessoryType can easily customizing the colors. support Flat Design same as iOS7.
 https://github.com/bitmapdata/MSCellAccessory